# Eloquent Models with relationships for lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Tags: oauth-2.0, eloquent, neoeloquent

anyone has actual Eloquent Models for the lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel package. Migrations are not very clear on the relationships, especially Many-to-Many. Not sure which side should be hasMany() vs belongsToMany(). Trying to follow the migrations to make models for Neo4j databases.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to relationships, given that all relations in Neo4j are directed:

- `hasMany` is an OUTGOING relationship `(node1)-[:REL]->(node2)` where `node1` can have multiple outgoing relationships of that kind
- `belongsToMany` is an INCOMING relationship `(node1)<-[:INCOME]-(node2)` where `node1` can have multiple incoming relationships of that kind

`node1` represents a model with a label (i.e. `User`) having relations such as `Post` (hasMany) and `Tag` (belongsToMany posts) so you'll have to define your relationships inside the model class as follows

```
class User
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'POSTED');
    }
}

class Post
{
    public function user()
    {
        // reverse of "posts" and must have the same name "POSTED"
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'POSTED'); 
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::class, 'TAGGED_WITH');
    }
}

class Tag
{
    public function posts()
    {
        // reverse of "tags" and must have the same name "TAGGED_WITH"
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'TAGGED_WITH');
    }
}
```

You'll end up with the following:

- `(:User)-[:POSTED]->(:Post)`
- `(:Post)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(:Tag)`

And you'll be able to refer to any node from any side.

I haven't used the package lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel but in case they have instructions on how the relationships between models should be, you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks for the respond. Yes, the lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel package is not very clear on which side is incoming/outgoing. Wish they had the actual Models instead of just migrations.